# error 503 en cron de panel ferozo

Tags: php, cron

les cuento mi problema....
Hace más de un año que tengo tareas programadas en un hosting compartido con panel ferozo que se venian ejecutando sin problemas.
Hace tres semanas, que las salidas de mis crons están dando

**HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Remote file exists and could contain further links,
but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.**

y en otros casos

**HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
Remote file does not exist -- broken link!!!**
(el archivo existe)

Lo raro, es que si el archivo que ejecuta el cron, lo ejecuto "a mano" hace todo lo que tiene que hacer sin ningún error

También les comento, que lo que hace ese archivo q se ejecuta es trae info de otra web, y con esa info se actualiza la base de datos que usamos nosotros.

Estuve leyendo varias cosas al respecto y uno de los comentarios es que quizá a la tarea ejecutada por el cron le deberia agregar un user agent.....el tema es cómo?

Aclaro que en el panel ferozo la configuracion viene asi  :

cronwget https://mirul.com/elArchivoEnSi.php --spider >/home/usuario/public_html/cron_actom3 2>&1

Alguien sabe cómo se puede agregar el user agent en esta línea?

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Si ejecutas cron desde el mismo servidor en dónde está el fichero .php, considera probar https://127.0.0.1 en lugar del dominio o primero asegurarte de que la url se resuelve bien desde el propio servidor. También tienes que tener en cuenta el usuario que se usa para ejecutar cron.